# Question about Google OAuth App Verification

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have an app which uses OAuth to grant scopes needed to access user data via YouTube Data API, then fetches YouTube data and puts it into a data warehouse. I have begun the Google App OAuth verification process and submitted several demo videos. I keep getting variants of this message from the verification team:

> Please provided an updated demo video how your app [app-name] uses the
> requested scope in regards to its definition:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly View your YouTube
> account https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner View and manage
> your assets and associated content on YouTube

The submitted demos show the code which makes requests to the YouTube Data API, requests which require the above scopes, and the resulting data stored in a data warehouse. This doesn't seem to be enough. I don't know in what other way I can show how my app uses the scopes as there is no app front-end where the data flow can be seen, the only front-end component is the OAuth interface for authorizing the scope usage. What else could my demo include to show the scope usage?

[Edit] This is the request shown in the demo:
[channel data request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KszR.jpg)

Comment: First off you can always email them back asking for certification,  Second did you send a video showing the consent screen running? Where the consent screen is displayed to the user and it shows both scopes being request as well as the name of your app appearing on the consent screen and your client id in the URL bar.

Comment: @DaImTo: Wouldn't be nicer that your comment be converted to an answer? I deem others in the OP's shoes would find that useful.

Comment: @stvar its not really an answer more pointers,  but okay.

Comment: @DaImTo: your points are important, in my opinion; in time, you may well evolve the text to a longer one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you can always email them back asking for certification.

Second did you send a video showing the consent screen running? This video should show the consent screen where it displays the scopes being requested.  It should also show the name of your application on the consent screen.   Finally it needs to show your client id in the url bar of the web browser.  **(THE BROWSER MUST BE SET TO ENGLISH)**

Comment: I've emailed back to continue the verification process after each new demo, and have also emailed asking for more precise requirements but always received a similar answer saying the demo doesn't show how the scopes are used.

Thanks for the suggestions. My browser is set to English, the demo shows the consent screen with the application redirect URL (app name is replaced by redirect URL for unverified apps), the individual scopes being requested, and the client id in the URL. The problem seems to be with the way we are using the scopes once they are granted.

Comment: well you are doing read calls show it reading the data?

Comment: The demo shows the API requests which are made (see edit in initial question), requests which require the demanded scopes, and the resulting data stored in BigQuery. Do you think going through the entire code flow from start to finish would be needed? From API client instantiation to writing the data to BigQuery.

Comment: @m.nicolau: (Since you're a newcomer SO user; please don't take this on a negative tonality), you may well [accept now and later even vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (when achieved 15+ points of reputation) the answer that provided you valuable info. Accepting and voting up an answer is good practice: (1) the one that proceeded that way gets himself/herself [points of reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and (2) the answer itself becomes more visible to other users within SO and Google searches. (Google is ranking SO answers intelligently).

Comment: @m.nicolau Send me a link to the video you are sending them, if you like i will have a look see if i can come up with any other ides.   I have several contact points in my profile here on SO.

Comment: @DaImTo I have sent you the demo URL via your website contact form as I didn't want to publicly post it here. Thank you!